# Could airliners have cameras to let the pilots see the engines and wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety

Why can't jet airliners have a camera installed on the fuselage and a monitor in the cockpit so that pilots can see engines and wings which are normally behind them and hidden from view? Something like the system they have in cars today?

This might help in an emergency engine fire or wing damage. I don't believe that any jet transport today has cameras to monitor the wings and engines (I see where they do have other cameras) and this was the cause of a recent accident where an engine was on fire after landing and the pilots were unaware of it until the fire was out of control and the pilots were almost killed.

Comment: Also [Why don't airliners have any mirrors or cameras?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16363/1696), but they're more intended for ground maneuvering than assessing damage.

Comment: Because cost is non-zero while benefit is small. Similarly why cars doesn't have fire extinguishers as standard equipment ?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact dupe: the other questions are focused on taxiing and visibility *around* the aircraft, whereas this one is about visibility *of* the aircraft itself. I suppose one camera could address both, but I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: *"a recent accident where an engine was on fire after landing and the pilots were unaware of it until the fire was out of control and the pilots were almost killed."* Which one was that? Flight number, aircraft tail number, anything on which to base a search?

Comment: China Airlines Flight 120. Smithsonian Air Disasters "Deadly Detail". Don't know tail number.

Comment: https://www.smithsonianchannel.com/videos/raw-footage-of-the-china-airlines-flight-120-explosion/59702